# Calculate the parameters $a_1, a_2, a_3,$ and $a_4$ so that the approximation of $u'$ is exact.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

*I'm given the following information:* one can obtain a higher order central difference scheme for the approximation of a first derivative $u',$ if one uses, for example, $u$-values at four grid points $x=-2h, \,x=-h,\, x=h$ and $x= 2h$.

The approximation of the first derivative at $x = 0$ is written in the form
$$(u'_0)_h = a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + a_3u_3 + a_4u_4$$
where $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and $a_4$ are parameters that must be calculated so that the scheme has the required accuracy.

**Exercise:** Calculate the parameters $a_1, a_2, a_3,$ and $a_4$ so that the approximation of $u'$ is exact for the functions $u(x) = 1, \,u(x) = x, \,u(x) = x^2,$ and $u(x) = x^3$.

I have no idea what to do. There were no central differencing schemes covered in the course I'm following and I can't figure them out myself (I didn't find much on the internet thus far).

**Question:** How do I calculate the parameters $a_1, a_2, a_3,$ and $a_4$?

Answer (score 2):

For $u(x)=1$, we have $u_1 = \dots = u_4 = 1$ and $u'(0) = 0$. Since we want the formula to be exact, we must have
$$
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 0 \, .
$$
For $u(x)=x$, we have $u_1 = -2h$, $u_2 = -h$, $u_3 = h$, $u_4 = 2h$ and $u'(0) = 1$. Since we want the formula to be exact, we must have
$$
\left(-2 a_1 - a_2 + a_3 + 2 a_4\right) h = 1 \, ,
$$
and so on and so forth for $u(x) = x^2$ and $u(x) = x^3$. Thus, the linear system
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \phantom{1} a_4 &= 0 \\
-2 a_1 - a_2 + a_3 + 2 a_4 &= 1/h \\
4 a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + 4 a_4 &= 0 \\
-8 a_1 - a_2 + a_3 + 8 a_4&= 0 \\
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
is obtained, with solution $a_1 = \frac{1}{12h}$, $a_2 = -\frac{2}{3h}$, $a_3 = \frac{2}{3h}$, $a_4 = -\frac{1}{12h}$. A Taylor series expansion gives
$$
\frac{u(-2h) - 8 u(-h) + 8 u(h) - u(2h)}{12h} \;\underset{(h\to 0)}{=}\; u'(0) - \frac{h^4}{30} u^{(5)}(0) + O(h^6) \, ,
$$
for all sufficiently smooth function $u$.

Comment: Just so that I'm sure that I understand: for $u(x) = x^2$ we would have $u_1 = 4h^2, u_2 = h^2,...$?

Comment: Because when I enter this system of equations in a solver I'm told that the input is invalid. I have \begin{split}
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 & = 0\\ 
-2ha_1 -ha_2 + ha_3 + 2ha_4 & = 1\\
4h^2a_1 + h^2a_2 + h^2a_3 + 4h^2a_4 & = 0\\
-8h^3a_1 -h^3a_2  + h^3a_3 + 8h^3a_4 & = 0
\end{split}

Comment: @titusAdam I edited my answer, which provides now a full solution.